# Can you close the SMTP port and still send emails?

Tags: smtp

Is an open SMTP port necessary when sending mails from an SMTP server?

From the design perspective, in a *client-server* architecture, this would not be needed, since SMTP server acts as a *client* connecting to other SMTP servers to send a mail.

But I'm not sure if the protocol itself requires a connection from outside too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to have the SMTP port - thatis, TCP 25 - open for incoming requests on the machine (e.g. your laptop) from which you're **sending** mail via a mailclient.

The SMTP port must be open only in a machine which is used as a SMTP server, i.e. to **receive** mail (and then either forward it to another mailserver up to its final destination, or deliver to a local inbox).

EDIT: If you need to use a SMTP server running on the **same** machine, in this case you make sure that the SMTP server is configured to accept SMTP connections from localhost only; it doesn't need to accept connections on port 25 from outside.
 
An open relay can be a big problem, as it can - and will - be abused to send spam. For this reason, most mailservers e.g. Sendmail, by default configuration, do not accept connections from outside.

Comment: The case is an application on the same server wants to use SMTP. From outside I want no client using it.

Comment: Ok, the application on the server wants to use SMTP.  Is it going to connect to a SMTP server running locally on the same machine, or to a remote SMTP server?

Comment: SAME server i said

Comment: In this case you configure the SMTP server running on the machine to accept SMTP connections from localhost only; it doesn't need to accept SMTP connections on port 25 from outside (a open relay can be a big problem, as it can - and will - be abused to send spam).

Comment: if you edit your answer to reflect that  it doesn't need to accept SMTP connections on port 25 from outside i can baptise it as the true answer

Comment: Ok, answer edited for clarity.